# How to ignore line breaks in regular expressions (C++)

Tags: c++, regex

How to ignore line breaks in regular expressions (C++).

PHP has a modifier "s" (single line):

```
$regex = "/<html>(.*)<\/html>/s";
```

If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it, newlines are excluded.

For example: https://regex101.com/r/jA4tT4/1

How to make it to C++?

Comment: Wasn't that ending up the regex string with a `$`?

Comment: Yes, C++ 11 (Visual C++)

Comment: By default you get `std::regex_constants::syntax_option_type::ECMAScript` which... is depressing, at best. JS doesn't have a `s` modifier nor does it support inline modifiers... The standard trick to overcome this is to use `[\s\S]` instead of `.`

Comment: Note that, if you use boost, you can have `syntax_option_type::perl` and... `syntax_option_type::mod_s`. yay!

Comment: With `ECMAScript` flag, you can try to use the suggestion from Lucas. `std::regex pttrn ("<html>([\\s\\S]+)</html>", std::regex::ECMAScript);`. Does it work?

Comment: stribizhev, does not work. I tried.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40904

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *sigh*... I thought they'd have fixed most bugs by now... well, use `(?:.|\r?\n)` then, I guess. Or a proper regex library :)

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski That's a good point actually - does \r count as part of "a newline" w.r.t. multi-line mode in this context? I've been using `(?:.|\n)` whoops

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit hmm I don't know if `\r` is included in `.` by default, and I *think* the answer wouldn't generalize to different regex libraries anyway.For instance, PCRE has 5 different options to choose from for what is a newline (CR, LF, CRLF, any of the previous, or any of the previous + Unicode newline sequences).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-atom https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#prod-LineTerminator Bah. (I'm only bothered about ECMAScript mode in this context.) So `[.\s]` (if it works) or `(?:.|\s)` is better.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yeah `(?:.|\s)` looks good. `[.\s]` doesn't match what you want here (only matches a period or whitespace).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Oh, right ^_^ I'd forgotten why I dropped the character class lol

Answer (score 2):

You can do a trick by using `[\s\S]*`. This is going to capturing everything from what you want to what you want.

So, you can have a regex like this:

```
<html>([\s\S]*)<\/html>    // greedy
<html>([\s\S]*?)<\/html>   // ungreedy
```

You can also use whatever shortcut you want like `[\d\D]` or `[\w\W]`

Btw, if you are parsing html, I'd use a html parser instead

Comment: `$regex = "/<html>([\s\S]*)<\/html>/";` isn't valid c++ code.

Comment: _"Can you suggest a change ..."_ Let's start making `$regex` a valid c++ variable?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ don't focus in the php code, just showed the regex to make the trick.

Comment: @DmitryScaletta have you tried with other combinations [\d\D] or [\w\W] ?

Comment: @DmitryScaletta great, glad to help. Is my answer answered to your question though?

Comment: @DmitryScaletta I'm not very knowledgeable in compiler discrepancies, but that seems like a deficiency in MSVC, as `\s` and `\S` are listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982727.aspx). Maybe someone else can clarify whether this is a bug or intended.

Comment: Warning ... this works on GCC and Clang/Linux, [but is broken on Clang/OSX](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40904). I've switched to `(?:.|\n)`.

Comment: Correction: `(?:.|\s)`